# How to call a angular library as different library name when lib import in project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular library.It's name is **@company/web** but I want to call  different name when import to project .For example **@web**.Can i do this without changing library name ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try adding it in your `tsconfig.json` of your project

inside `paths` property add reference to your library like this

```
"paths": {
      "@web": ["node_modules/@company/web"]
    }
```

And please do restart you angular app and localhost server

Comment: yes now you will be able to use @web instead of "node_modules/.....web"